# Databricks named_struct strange behaviour with backslash in value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, databricks, databricks-sql

How is it possible to handle backslash as is with named_struct?

I am trying to achieve the return value of:
`{"test": "DE844\/374"}`

a) with this:
`SELECT named_struct('test', "DE844\/374");`

return value is:
`{"test": "DE844/374"}`

b) with this:
`SELECT named_struct('test', "DE844\\/374");`

return value is:
`{"test": "DE844\\/374"}`

Answer (score 0):

I think only way to get `\` backslash character is to use `decode()` function by using unicode(`\u005C`) character sets.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',)],['a'])
df.withColumn("str",(expr('concat("DE844",decode("\\u005C", "utf-8"),"/374")'))).show(10,False)
#+---+----------+
#|a  |str       |
#+---+----------+
#|a  |DE844\/374|
#+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` twice:

```py
spark.sql("select named_struct('test', 'DE844\\\\/374' ) as a ").show()

#+------------+
#|           a|
#+------------+
#|[DE844\/374]|
#+------------+
```